# How to redirect and append using Bash shell?

Tags: linux, append, io-redirection

I am trying to execute this command for a Linux assignment, but I cannot figure out what the command should be. I know how to append to a file - you use the `>>`. But I am not sure how to redirect and append the output together:

9. Redirect the output of the process list (ps) only for httpd process appending it to final.txt (file created in step 5)

How do I redirect and append the output together?

Thank you!

Comment: @GillesQuenot yes it is for my homework but I am just stcuk trying to figure out this step

Comment: `>>` is a redirection which appends stdout to a file. You're not expected to do redirection and then also append as two separate steps the way you interpreted it, it's just asking you to use the `>>` redirection to append to a file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See below:

```
ps -C httpd | grep httpd >> final.txt
```

**Explanation:**

`ps -C httpd` prints out the ps entry related to `httpd` command only in the form like:

```
  PID TTY         TIME CMD
14308 pts/0   00:00:00 httpd
```

so we have the entry what we need with headers (`PID`, `TTY` etc.).

To filter-out headers we pipe this output to `grep httpd`, which pushes to its out the lines containing string `httpd` only, like:

```
14308 pts/0   00:00:00 httpd
```

Finally, we redirect this output to file `final.txt` in append mode, using `>>` operator.

Comment: You should add some explanation

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
ps auxwww | grep '[h]ttpd' >> final.txt
```

Note the

```
[h]
```

trick is important to not grep the command itself

Comment: No, have you tested ?

Answer (score 0):

">>" redirects to the end of the file.txt. If you use only ">" it will replace the whole content of the file.txt.

```
ps | grep httpd | grep -v grep >> final.txt
```